# Rotted bottom of wood siding

Tags: siding

Some siding boards started to rot at the bottom. See pictures. How can it be repaired without replacing entire board?

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

-Leon

Answer (score 2):

High performance 2-part wood putty.